# Configure duration of Non-Renewing Subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I need to add `Non-Renewing Subscription` into my app. I've opened `iTunesConnect` and added  In-App Purchase with type `Non-Renewing`, but I can't find any fields to configure an exact duration of my subscription.

How do I set the duration of my subscription?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike auto-renewable subscriptions, in non-renewing subscriptions you need to handle the duration yourself.

Follow this tutorial - 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial

Comment: So, does **Restore Purchases** work only for **Auto-renewable subscriptions**?

Comment: what if after 1 month subscription user wants to renew his/her subscription? Apple will say "hey man, u already bought it " and restore his subscription. How will I should this problem?

Comment: Not sure that I understand the question. Are you talking about auto renewing purchase or non-renewing purchase?

Comment: Apple spare no efforts to make everything difficult.

Comment: Yes restore purchases only work for Auto-renewable subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle expiration and renewing of `Non-Renewing Subscription` items by yourself (at your server, in your db). Apple/StoreKit takes no part in it.

It's actually quite similar to `Non-consumables` items. The only difference is that `Non-consumables` items can only be bought once whereas `Non-Renewing Subscription` items can be bought any number of times.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/86112)